# Custom Validation is not working in angular

Tags: angular

I have defined a custom validation as :

```
static cannotContainSpace(control:AbstractControl):ValidationErrors | null{

        if((control.value as string).indexOf('') >=0 )
                return{cannotContainSpace :true};
        return null;
    }
```

and in my component I am using the following code:

```
<input formControlName="username"id="username" type="text" class="form-control">
    <div *ngIf="form.get('username').touched && form.get('username').errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">username required</div>

    <div *ngIf="form.get('username').errors?.minlength" class="alert alert-danger">username should be of minimum 3 characters.</div>
    <div *ngIf="form.get('username').errors.cannotContainSpace" class="alert alert-danger">There can be no spaces in Username.</div>
</div>
```

My issue is that despite using ngIf in the customValidation ,the div tag or the corresponding error messages are being displayed even with the non space text or whenever the page is freshly loaded.
ANy suggestions?

Comment: if (/\s/.test(control.value)) {
    // It has any kind of whitespace
}

Comment: check if form conrol is dirty first form.get('username').dirty && form.get('username').errors.cannotContainSpace